# Run a program on this Christmas and then every few hours

Tags: automation

My girlfriend has sort of strong perversion for colored stripes. She likes stripes on everything.

So I decided I could set up a little surprise for Christmas and I made I [program that generates pretty colored stripes and sets them as windows desktop](https://gist.github.com/Darker/ecf315591def7ae25c5d) immediately.

[image: striped windows background]

I now need to make sure this program will eventually start generating the backgrounds for her after Christmas (24.12 this year - 2014). However I can't get to her computer without her knowing very often so I need to set up something automated.

Best solution is the one that can be easily disabled without my assistance (eg. if she tells me she doesn't like it anymore)

What can I do?

Comment: Sorry about offtopic but you can use find nice color palletes for stripes here: [link to colourlovers.com](http://www.colourlovers.com/palettes/most-loved/all-time/)

Comment: It would be cool if I could fetch their stream into my program and turn a palete into color distribution.

Comment: Nice idea. Everything is possible. All you have to do is parse HTML/CSS and extract colors.

Comment: I already started thinking up some XML definition for a RandomColor class. But I can't make that in time so there will probably be a Easter update :)

Comment: I think total random is bad idea. Read about color harmonies. You can make 1 random color and calculate harmonic colors for it by shifting hue. http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-harmonies.htm

Comment: @Kamil I'm not making totally random colors anymore. Instead I have sets of colors. I'm also playing with color distributions to remove unpleasant colors (she doesn't like pink, yellow and magenta) from the hue circle.

Comment: So, looks like you are serious about this :) I hope that little scientific approach (after you read bout these color harmonies) will make your girlfriend more happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using Windows Task Scheduler. You can find it by searching in Control Panel. Create a new task, point it to your program executable, and set it to run daily starting from Christmas.

If you are able to, you'll probably want to test out your settings beforehand by setting an earlier date and have it run frequently.

As far as disabling it, it should be quite easy to open Task Scheduler again and hitting "Disable" on the task.